# Посчитать количество красивых чисел

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, оптимизация, теория-чисел

На просторах интернета нашел интересную задачу:

*Нужно посчитать кол-во красивых (сумма первых шести чисел равна сумме шести последних цифр) 13-значных чисел в 13-значной системе счисления, например:
число 0055237050A00 - красивое, так как 0+0+5+5+2+3 = 0+5+0+A+0+0, а
число 1234AB988BABA - некрасивое, так как 1+2+3+4+A+B != 8+8+B+A+B+A*

Я решил написать класс для этого, который будет хранить число в преобразованном в массив виде:

```
struct Number
{
    explicit Number(size_t number);
    Number& operator ++ ();
    Number& operator ++ (int);
    bool is_beautiful() const;
private:
    std::array<uint8_t, 13> m_digits;
};
```

И потом в цикле проверять все числа в интервале:

```
Number number{ 0u };
size_t count_numbers = 0u;
for (size_t i = 0u; i < std::pow(13,13); ++i) {
    count_numbers |= (number++).is_beautiful();
}
```

Но хотел спросить насколько это оптимальное решение, может быть можно как-то обойтись без массива с использованием арифметики? Если да, то как тогда это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 5):

Ну проверять все числа в большом интервале - не наш метод...

Подумайте вот о чём: количество сумм 6 цифр невелико - всего 73 - от 0 до 72 (исправлено по замечанию mathewsun)

Если мы знаем, что слева сумма k может быть в F(k) вариантах, то справа то же самое, и существует F(k)*F(k) красивых чисел с такой суммой. Выполнив суммирование для всех k в указанном диапазоне, получим общее количество красивых чисел (если умножим полученную сумму на 13 для учёта центральной цифры, которая может быть любой)

```
N = 13 * (F(0)*F(0)+F(1)*F(1)+...F(72)*F(72))
```

F(k) можно найти математически, но в простом случае достаточно перебрать все 4.8 миллиона чисел из 6 знаков, для каждого считать сумму цифр, и увеличивать соответствующий счётчик в массиве из 73 целых чисел.

```
F = [0]*73
for i in range(13**6):
    t = i
    s = 0
    while t:
        s += t % 13  #очередная 13-ричная цифра
        t //= 13
    F[s] += 1

count = 0
for i in range(73):
    count += F[i]*F[i]

print(count*13)

>>>9203637295151
```

Comment: Ваш ответ надо бы объединить с ответом @Harry . У вас теория, у него практика.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Пусть расцветают сто цветов, как Мао говорил :) Ну я-то обычно надеюсь, что автору вопроса подсказок хватит.

Comment: c*6 = 72, c = 12. не 79 а 72 значения

Comment: Результат равен 46767020079. Ссылка на репозиторий в комментарии ниже.

Comment: @mathewsun  73 (0..72). А ответ у Harry верный, вы где-то ошиблись, наверное

Comment: У него проблема в переполнении `int`.

Answer (score 4):

По сути у вас задача о количестве счастливых билетов длиной 12 в 13-ричной системе счисления, умноженное на 13 (средняя цифра).

Функция для числа билетов произвольной длины в произвольной системе счисления выглядит так:

```
unsigned long long happy(unsigned int n, unsigned int base)
{
    if (n%2 || n < 2 || base < 2) throw runtime_error("Wrong data");
    auto N = [](unsigned int n, unsigned int k,
                unsigned int base, auto&&N)
    {
        if (n == 1) return (unsigned long long)(k < base);
        unsigned long long s = 0;
        for(unsigned int l = 0; l < base; ++l) s += N(n-1,k-l,base,N);
        return s;
    };
    unsigned long long s = 0;
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k <= (base-1)*n/2; ++k)
    {
        auto m = N(n/2,k,base,N);
        s += m*m;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Теперь, чтоб посчитать все счастливые билеты в задании, надо написать

```
cout << 13*happy(12,13) << endl;
```

P.S. Алгоритм для написания функции взят из набора очень интересных статей по адресу: http://www.ega-math.narod.ru/Quant/Tickets.htm

P.P.S. Результат посчитан [тут](https://ideone.com/bKXCqb), и он равен 9203637295151.

Comment: Ваш ответ надо бы объединить с ответом @Mbo. У вас практика, у него теория.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Надо в мете обсудить предложение о коллективных ответах :)

Comment: `по разному смотреть на одну и ту же задачу` для шестизначных билетиков я когда-то для себя  представлял количество сумм как количество целочисленных точек на сечении куба плоскостью, отсекающей равные отрезки по осям - треугольное или шестиугольное сечение.

Comment: Сделали на c#. https://github.com/mathewsun/HappyTickets13 Результат равен 46767020079.

Comment: @mathewsun Если устранить переполнения при вычислении, ваш результат совпадёт с моим...

Answer (score 0):

Сделали на c#

Количество сумм 6 цифр не 79, а 72.

Не забываем умножить еще на 13, так как по середине есть еще одно число.

Результат равен 9203637295151

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] numbers = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C' };
        //char[] numbers = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }; 

        var maxSum = Sum("CCCCCC");
        //var maxSum = Sum("9999"); 

        //индекс массива - сумма чисел, значение ячейки - количество комбинаций 
        long[] maxSums = new long[maxSum + 1];
        var count = numbers.Count();

        for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < count; b++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < count; c++)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < count; d++)
                    {
                        for (int e = 0; e < count; e++)
                        {
                            for (int f = 0; f < count; f++)
                            {
                                var index = a + b + c + d + e + f; 
                                ++maxSums[index];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        long result = 0;

        var x = Sum("CCCCCC");
        //var x = Sum("9999"); 
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSums.Count(); ++i)
        {
            result += maxSums[i] * maxSums[i];
        }
  
        Console.WriteLine($"Actual result:\n{result}");

        //Умножаем еще на 1, потому что посередине есть цифра, которая не учитывается при подсчёте комбинаций
        Console.WriteLine($"Actual result * 13:\n{result * 13}");

        //для 13 значных 13-теричных счастливых билетиков получаем 46767020079 счастливых билетиков
    }
    public static int Sum(string str)
    {
        int x = 0;
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            x += ConvertToInt13(c.ToString());
        }

        return x;
    }

    public static int ConvertToInt13(string str)
    {
        if (str == "A")
        {
            return 10;
        }
        if (str == "B")
        {
            return 11;
        }
        if (str == "C")
        {
            return 12;
        }

        return int.Parse(str);
    }
```

Репо выложили здесь - https://github.com/mathewsun/HappyTickets13

Comment: Добавил в ваш код строку отладочного вывода — `for (int i = 0; i < maxSums.Count(); ++i)
            {
                result += maxSums[i] * maxSums[i];
                Console.WriteLine($"result:{result}\n");
            }` Получаю такие, например, подряд идущие значения: `result:3399502191

result:2841634840

result:1721459068

result:55004320

result:1987572132

result:2897800573` Дальше пояснять, где проблема, не требуется?

Comment: Замените `var maxSums = new int[maxSum + 1];` на `long[] maxSums = new long[maxSum + 1];` и посмотрите на результат (и сравните с моим)...

Comment: Часто встречающееся тонкое место, что разрядности промежуточных данных maxSums хватает, а вычисления с ними по умолчанию производятся в 32 битах, `result += (long) maxSums[i] * maxSums[i];` уже спасает

Comment: @Harry спасибо большое! Действительно здесь был недочёт и терялись данные. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Решал задачку на C# и уже после решения нашел это обсуждение.
Хотел сначала выразить аналитически, но увы...
Как следствие пошел по пути динамического программирования)))
Сначала через рекурсию, но переписал на нерекурсивный вариант.

```
long GetLuckyTicketCount(int digitsCount, int numeralSystem)
{
    int maxDigitValue = numeralSystem - 1;
    
    // инициализируем матрицу для частичных решений
    var partialSolutions = new long[digitsCount][];
    partialSolutions[0] = new long[numeralSystem];
    for (int k = 0; k <= maxDigitValue; ++k)
    {
        partialSolutions[0][k] = 1;
    }
    
    for (int n = 1; n < digitsCount; ++n)
    {
        int maxSum = (n + 1) * maxDigitValue;
        partialSolutions[n] = new long[maxSum + 1];
        for (int k = maxSum; k >= 0; --k)
        {
            int statIndex = Math.Max(0, k - n * maxDigitValue);
            for (int i = statIndex; i < numeralSystem && i <= k; ++i)
            {
                partialSolutions[n][k] += partialSolutions[n - 1][k - i];
            }
        }
    }

    long result = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k <= maxDigitValue * digitsCount; ++k)
    {
        result += partialSolutions[digitsCount - 1][k] * partialSolutions[digitsCount - 1][k];
    }
    return result;
}
```

https://github.com/Vovanda/BeautifulNumbers/blob/master/Service/BeautifulNumbersService.cs

P.S Однако я удивлен, что никто не решил сохранять промежуточные вычисления